# Diff between uint16_t and uint32_t

Tags: c, raspbian, bit-shift

In my code there is no difference between uint16_t and uint32_t. Why?

I am using Raspbian on a RasPi with ARMv7 (32bit).

```
root@zentrale:/src# uname -a
Linux zentrale 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

This is the code:

```
void main()
{

        uint16_t wert1;
        uint32_t wert2;

        int i;

        wert1=2;
        wert2=2;
        for (i=0; i<33;i++)
        {
                printf("i: %2d\tLShifted wert1: %10u\t",i,wert1 << i);
                printf("RShifted wert1: %10u\t",wert1 >> i);
                printf("LShifted wert2: %10u\t",wert2 << i);
                printf("RShifted wert2: %10u\n",wert2 >> i);
        }
exit(0);
}
```

This is the stripped output:

```
i:  0   LShifted wert1:          2      RShifted wert1:          2      LShifted wert2:          2      RShifted wert2:          2
i:  1   LShifted wert1:          4      RShifted wert1:          1      LShifted wert2:          4      RShifted wert2:          1
[...]
i: 14   LShifted wert1:      32768      RShifted wert1:          0      LShifted wert2:      32768      RShifted wert2:          0
i: 15   LShifted wert1:      65536      RShifted wert1:          0      LShifted wert2:      65536      RShifted wert2:          0
i: 16   LShifted wert1:     131072      RShifted wert1:          0      LShifted wert2:     131072      RShifted wert2:          0
[...]
```

I would have expected the wert1 being 16bits getting to zero with the i=15 value as the name tells it is 16bits long.

Instead there is no difference in these two variables.

I found some reference of the max value of uint16_t in Raspian (see https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/memory/variables)

So why is there no difference?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `uint16_t` variable is promoted to `int` for the arithmetic operation, and because an `int` is passed to `printf` the promotion remains. However, it is *undefined behaviour* to shift a 16-bit variable by more than 15 bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is undefined to shift a value by more bits than its width. But since `int` is 32-bit wide then it is undefined only when it is pushed to the sign bit. But 33 is just plain evil! it does not even have a well-specified hardware meaning! Common cases include it zeroing, not doing anything, shifting by 33 mod 32 = 1 bits or generating an exception...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Missed case: undefined to shift a value by its width - regardless of value. e.g. `0 << 32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Both operands of `<<` will undergo **integer promotions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3), i.e. [C11 6.3.11p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.

Since `int` on your platform is 32-bits wide, all values of `uint16_t` are representable by `int`. The `uint32_t` is converted to `unsigned int`!

Now the behaviours of both of them *seem* equal **because** GCC guarantees most of that! All signed arithmetic on all architectures that are supported by GCC use 2's complement; and [additionally GCC does not consider the behaviour `<<` on signed numbers as undefined in the cases where the sign bit is changed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation).

However, it is **still** undefined (even in GCC) what happens if the shift width is greater than or equal to the width of the operand (in this case 32 bits), so `<< 32` and `<< 33` will have undefined behaviour.

Other than that, in general the C standard says that the behaviour is undefined if a positive signed integer is left-shifted so that the sign bit changes! This happens when you shift a `uint16_t` left by so many bits that it will change the shift bit of `int`. Hence,

```
(uint16_t)0xFFFF << 16
```

has undefined behaviour on 32-bit platform, because the topmost bit is shifted to the sign bit of `int`, whereas

```
(uint32_t)0xFFFF << 16
```

does not, because the latter would use unsigned arithmetic. As always, a compiler can define behaviour beyond that which is required by the standard.

Comment: Example of gcc UB for left shift into the sign bit: https://godbolt.org/z/IYhQd8. The compiler translates `i32 = i32 << 31 >> 31;` to `mvn     r1, #0`, which is not correct for neither arithmetic nor logical right shift. Change type to unsigned and you get `mov     r1, #1` as expected.

Comment: @Lundin `mvn` is move not, so 0xFFFFFFFF is moved to r1, which is arithmetic right shift

Comment: This was the ARM port. The x86-64 port does `mov     esi, -1` which probably works as expected. Regardless, I wouldn't trust that GCC guarantees anything.

Comment: The behaviour has been documented: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation

Comment: "mvn is move not" Ach okay my bad then, not used to reading ARM assembler!

Comment: @Lundin this was new to me too :P google ftw . Remember that ARM has rather limited immediates

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference because of **Integer Promotions**

You should really go through this excellent post on the subject [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Assuming 4 byte `int`, before any arithmetic operation an `uint16_t` is converted to a  signed `int` and then the operation is carried out.

A left shift on a negative number is undefined. But in this case, this number cannot be negative. So you will get the same output as a `uint32_t`

You should typecast the output of the left shift for proper operation.

Also, you are running the loop until `i<33`. At `i==32`, you will have undefined behaviour for `uint32_t` and at `i==31` you will have undefined behaviour for signed integer for `uint16_t`

```
 printf("i: %2d\tLShifted wert1: %10u\t",i,  (uint16_t)(wert1 << i);
```

Comment: The UB will start at `i == 30` since `2 << 30` causes signed integer overflow

Comment: Got it. Used (uint16_t) wert1<<i instead of (uint16_t)(wert1<<i).

Results seems to be accurate now. Thanks!

Comment: "You should typecast the output of the left shift for proper operation." is unclear and possible incorrect. The correct type likely needs to be used before the shift.